# String to date during INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, string, oracle, date, insert

I need to add a string ('taskdate') using the string to date conversion function, can you tell me how to do it?

Below is the standard add procedure, what do I need to change?

```
INSERT INTO SHIFTASKS ('taskcounter', 'vehid', 'taskdate', 'shift', 'tabelnum')
VALUES (100293896, 57, '13.01.14 00:00:00', 2, 600607);
```

P.S. I've read about the "cast" and "convert" functions, but I can't figure out how to use them during the insert into command.
DBMS - Oracle

Comment: Ps. I just started studying sql.

Comment: DBMS - Oracle..

Comment: Have a look at the [syntax for literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Literals.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
INSERT INTO SHIFTASKS (taskcounter, vehid, taskdate, shift, tabelnum)
VALUES (100293896, 57, to_date('13.01.14 00:00:00','DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:DD'), 2, 600607);
```